# how to make readable the url of an image that comes from an api that I created?

Tags: laravel, api, rest, laravel-api

I created an api it's been 2 weeks. the api works well but I can't retrieve the images from this api during my HTTP requests.

My Controller Api/admin/AgencyController

`

public function store(AgencyRequest $request)
{

```
    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {

        $path = $request->file('logo')->store('logo','public');
       }
    $agency=Agency::create([
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'headquarters'=>$request->headquarters,
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'logo'=>$path,
        'phone_number'=>$request->phone_number,
        'state'=>$request->state,
        'password'=>bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);

    return new AgencyResource($agency);
}
```

`

My index file

`

```
  @foreach ($datas as $agencies)
                                        @forelse ($agencies as $agency)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><img src="{{ url('https://kipart.stillforce.tech/storage/'.$agency->logo) }}" width="48" alt="Product img"></td>
                                                <td><h5>{{ $agency->logo }}</h5></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.agencies.edit',$agency->id) }}" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-float btn-sm waves-green"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></a>

                                                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.agencies.destroy', $agency->id) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                                                        @csrf
                                                        @method('delete')
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-float btn-sm waves-red"  ><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete" aria-hidden="true" title="Suprimer"></i></button>

                                                       </form>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
```

`

```
  @foreach ($datas as $agencies)
                                        @forelse ($agencies as $agency)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><img src="{{ url('https://kipart.stillforce.tech/storage/'.$agency->logo) }}" width="48" alt="Product img"></td>
                                                <td><h5>{{ $agency->logo }}</h5></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.agencies.edit',$agency->id) }}" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-float btn-sm waves-green"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></a>

                                                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.agencies.destroy', $agency->id) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                                                        @csrf
                                                        @method('delete')
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-float btn-sm waves-red"  ><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete" aria-hidden="true" title="Suprimer"></i></button>

                                                       </form>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
```

When I do a test registration of an agency. all the data is registered but when I retrieve the image to a flutter client or a laravel client the image does not appear but all the data is called

Comment: you are using the `url()` helper then you are including the `https://kipart.stillforce.tech`.  If you are using the `url()` helper the hostname is already included so the only thing you need to put inside is the `path`. Try removing the `https://kipart.stillforce.tech` then check if it works.

Comment: @xenooooo thank you for your help, but the images are still not displayed, I would like to know whether to create a GET route to call it directly on url()?